# Proxying nifi using nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I want to use an https nginx to proxy a non-secured nifi server running in the same box.

So far the closest I get is by using this configuration:

```
location ^~ /nifi {
            proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost localhost;
            proxy_set_header X-ProxyPort 6969;
            proxy_set_header X-ProxyContextPath /nifi;

            proxy_pass http://localhost:6969/nifi;
    }
```

In nifi I get the exception:

```
2018-11-24 17:40:19,473 ERROR [NiFi Web Server-20] o.a.nifi.web.api.config.ThrowableMapper An unexpected error has occurred:
javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilderException: The provided context path [/nifi] was not whitelisted []. Returning Internal Server Error response.
javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilderException: The provided context path [/nifi] was not whitelisted []
        at org.apache.nifi.web.util.WebUtils.verifyContextPath(WebUtils.java:152)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.util.WebUtils.getResourcePath(WebUtils.java:125)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.api.ApplicationResource.buildResourceUri(ApplicationResource.java:159)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.api.ApplicationResource.generateResourceUri(ApplicationResource.java:141)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.api.ProcessorResource.populateRemainingProcessorEntityContent(ProcessorResource.java:107)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.api.ProcessorResource.populateRemainingProcessorEntitiesContent(ProcessorResource.java:95)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.api.FlowResource.populateRemainingFlowStructure(FlowResource.java:200)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.api.FlowResource.populateRemainingFlowContent(FlowResource.java:187)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.api.FlowResource.getFlow(FlowResource.java:373)
```

Any hints?

Comment: Check your error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your `proxy_pass` to remove the `nifi` suffix.

```
location ^~ /nifi {

    proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost localhost;
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyPort 6969;
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyContextPath /nifi;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:6969;

}
```

nginx will append the entire `$uri` to the `proxy_pass` url, so nginx was forwarding to http://localhost:6969/nifi/nifi/... instead of http://localhost:6969/nifi/...

Comment: Still the same error after correcting the proxy pass entry

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the answer [above](https://serverfault.com/a/941501/508541), try adding the `X-ProxyScheme` header.

Also, if you are advertising your site for external access, modify the `X-ProxyHost` to your LAN accessible IP address or Internet accessible domain name. (i.e. `mynifiwebaccess.com`,`10.51.102.9`)

```
location ^~ /nifi {

    proxy_set_header X-ProxyScheme https;
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost mynifiwebaccess.com;
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyPort <externally_advertised_port_number>;
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyContextPath /nifi;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:6969;

}
```

I am not sure about your configuration but you could try making the port number for the `externally_advertised_port` on the code above different since NiFi might be running and using port `6969` already.

Answer (score 0):

the error message: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilderException: The provided context path [/nifi] was not whitelisted [].

this is caused by nifi.web.proxy.context.path is not set properly.

check the doc:

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.3.0/nifi-configuration-best-practices/content/proxy_configuration.html